# Websocket blocking my jQuery from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I included a web-socket to my website, and now all of my jQuery code stopped working.

I don't know what the problem is. How can I fix this?

Here is the full jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = parseInt($('#counter').val(), 10);

    $("#postcount").on("click", function(){
        var z = i ++;
        $('#counter').val(z);
        alert(z);
    });
});
```

**Websocket script**

```
var socket;
function init() {
    var host = "ws://127.0.0.1:9000/echobot";
    try {
        socket = new WebSocket(host);
        //log('WebSocket - status '+socket.readyState);
        log('1');
    }
    catch(ex){ 
        log(ex); 
    }
    $("msg").focus();
}
function send(){
    var txt,msg;
    txt = $("msg");
    msg = txt.value;
    if(!msg) { 
        log("Message can not be empty");
        return; 
    }
    txt.value="";
    txt.focus();
    try { 
        socket.send(msg); 
        log("<b>"+msg+"</b>"); 
    } catch(ex) { 
        log(ex); 
    }
}

// Utilities
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function log(msg) {
    $("log").innerHTML = msg;
}
function onkey(event) {
    if(event.keyCode==13) {
        send();
    }
}
```

**Home page**

```
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="log"></div>
    <input id="msg" type="textbox" onkeypress="onkey(event)" 
                                   onchange="send()" onkeyup="send()"/>
    <button onclick="send()">Send</button>
    <br/>

    <input id="counter" type="textbox" value="2"/>
    <input type="button" id="postcount" class="postcount" value="Reconnect"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you at least checked the console for errors?

Comment: I couldn't find what the problem is from console @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: what is `function $(id)`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ i never check what is does i downloaded web-socket few hours ago let me remove it and run the script to see what will happen

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ i just tried to remove it and the web-socket stopped working and also the jquery didn't work too

Comment: well `function $(id){` is probably overriding jQuery because you are redefining what `$('element')` does.  It used to return a jQuery object but you've overriden it to return a dom element with that particular ID.  switch the function name or for `jQuery`  - use `jQuery('element')` instead of `$('element')`

Comment: You can also try scoping your jQuery code so the `$` will work inside the document.ready like `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ I just did but still same

Comment: The `$` function for jQuery is being overwritten.

Comment: Yes, change the name of function $(id) with other name example getElement(id) but is not necesary if you are using jquery. with jquery you can get it wirh $("#id") of element html. my suggestion is use jquery direct.

Answer (score 0):

try it full example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = parseInt($('#counter').val(), 10);

    $("#postcount").on("click", function(){
        var z = i ++;
        $('#counter').val(z);
        alert(z);
    });

    init();
});

var socket;
function init() {

    var SO = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;

    var host = "ws://127.0.0.1:9000/echobot";
    try {
        socket = new SO(host);
        //log('WebSocket - status '+socket.readyState);
        log('1');
    }
    catch(ex){ 
        log(ex); 
    }

    $("msg").trigger("focus");
}
function send(){
    var txt,msg;
    txt = $("#msg");
    msg = txt.val("");
    if(!msg) { 
        log("Message can not be empty");
        return; 
    }
    txt.val("");
    txt.focus();
    try { 
        socket.send(msg); 
        log("<b>"+msg+"</b>"); 
    } catch(ex) { 
        log(ex); 
    }
}


function log(msg) {
    $("#log").html(msg);
}
function onkey(event) {
    if(event.keyCode==13) {
        send();
    }
}
```